# JSON service class not defined client side

Tags: javascript, json, wcf, web-services

I've got a bunch of JSON service classes used via ajax calls in my asp.net website. All have been working fine until a couple days ago, one of the classes stopped being visible client side.

It's called ExceptionsJSONService and when I try to instantiate it in javascript via

```
var service = new ExceptionsJSONService();
```

I get "Object Expected". I can't figure out what could have changed since it was working fine. I've checked the web.config and the service is defined there via:

```
    <behavior name="ExceptionsJSONServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
      <enableWebScript />
    </behavior>
```

and later:

```
  <service name="ExceptionsJSONService">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="ExceptionsJSONServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ExceptionsJSONService" />
  </service>
```

It's defined in the Master page via ScriptManager in:

```
<asp:ServiceReference Path="~/Services/ExceptionsJSONService.svc" />
```

I have the service file which contains the following:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="ExceptionsJSONService" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/ExceptionsJSONService.cs" %>
```

And I have the actual class definition file, the header of which is:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class ExceptionsJSONService : BaseJSONService {}
```

I've omitted the body of the class due to length but it builds fine and is identical excepting the name to all my other JSONService classes.

Comment: Could you please check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924552.aspx for missing configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by a public function defined in the ExceptionsJSONService class. The function is supposed to be public but it was also marked as an Operation Contract.

In the parameter list for the function was our EF DB context object. Because it was in the parameter list for an Operation Contract it caused the service to search for Data Contracts for all the entities associated with the DB context. This caused an exception to be thrown that only showed up in the service trace logs. The exception prevented the service from loading properly so when I would try to instantiate the service client side in javascript it would fail.

Removing the Operation Contract attribute from the function resolved the issue.